# About send request and receive response with netty asynchronously

Tags: netty

In a client,i want send a request message asynchronously,and then receive a response with respect to this request,here is my code,it does work correctly,but i have doubt about this is thread-safe,cause my poor knowledge about concurrency and netty:
code of client:
***(note:request and response correlated with key typed long)***

```
public class RequestSender{

    private int connectTimeout;
    private boolean soKeepAlive = true;

    public RequestSender(Properties props) {
        connectTimeout = 20000;
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 9686;
        this.soKeepAlive = true;

        createNettyHandler();
        try {
            boostrapNettyClient(host, port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createNettyHandler() {
        this.handler = new RequestSenderHandler ();
    }
    public ResponseFuture send(RequestMessage request) {

            ResponseFuture future = new ResponseFuture();
            this.handler.futureMap.put(request.getKey(), future);
            this.handler.send(request);
            return future;
    }

    RequestSenderHandler handler;

    final static class RequestSenderHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<NeedleWriteResult> {
        ChannelHandlerContext chnlCtx = null;
        @Override
        public void channelRegistered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Connection registered");
        }
        
        @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Connection active");
            this.chnlCtx = ctx;
        }
        protected Map<Long,ResponseFuture> futureMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ResponseFuture result) throws Exception {
            futureMap.get(result.getKey()).setResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }
        
        public ChannelFuture send(Request request) {
            try {
                if(chnlCtx != null) {
                    ChannelPromise promise = new DefaultChannelPromise(chnlCtx.channel());
                    return chnlCtx.writeAndFlush(request,promise);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void boostrapNettyClient(String host, int port) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline()
                .addLast(new RequestEncoder())
                .addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE,0, 4,0,4))
                .addLast(new ResponseDecoder())
                .addLast(handler)
                ;
            }
        })
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
        ;
        b.connect(host, port).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Connection established");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Connection attempt failed");
                    future.cause().printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
Here is my custom future:

    public class ResponseFuture implements Future<Response> {
        public CountDownLatch latch;
        private Response result = null;
        public ResponseFuture() {
            this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        }
        public void setResult(Response result) {
            this.result = result;
            this.latch.countDown();
        }
        public Response get() throws InterruptedException {
            this.latch.await();
            return this.result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public Response get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
                throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            this.latch.await(timeout, unit);
            return this.result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In Netty the goal is to not to block the EventLoop threads of the channels. As long as the The consumer of your client (the code that call ResponseFuture.get()) is not running on the EventLoop threads, the code looked OK to me in terms of concurrency issues. However some choices looked odd a bit, like channel reading a ResponseFuture instead of a Response. In genral if you can avoid any blocking contructs like Latches and use event handlers. you will reduce the risk of blocking the EventLoop threads, here is Netty client example: https://github.com/timboudreau/netty-http-client hope it helps

Comment: I want to use connection pool for  netty channel to handle multiple threads,but doubt this is necessary.Is a netty channel can be used with multiple threads?

Comment: Multiple Threads can write to a Channel, (Channel.write is thread safe). Channel itself is owned by single EventLoop thread, So the code being executed on the channel pipeline is executed by a single thread. (you can configure a certain handler to be executed by a different thread pool). The performance of Netty comes from being asycn and not using too many threads. In read scenario, you can either handle incoming response without blocking on the channel thread. Or If you need to block, pass it a different thread pool. Did you get the chance to read the Netty in Action book?